# javascript: generate 2 random but distinct numbers from range

Tags: javascript, random, sampling

quick question:

What is the best way for implementing this line of python code (generates two random but distinct numbers from a given range)...

```
random.sample(xrange(10), 2)
```

...in Javascript?

Thanks in advance!

Martin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my attempt using splice:

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];var sample = [];
sample.push(a.splice(Math.random()*a.length,1));
sample.push(a.splice(Math.random()*a.length,1));
```

Wrapped in a function:

```
function sample_range(range, n) {
  var sample = [];
  for(var i=0; i<n; i++) {
    sample.push(range.splice(Math.random()*range.length,1));
  }

  return sample;
}

var sample = sample_range([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 2);
```

We could also stick the function into Array.prototype to have something like dot notation syntax:

```
Array.prototype.sample_range = function(n) {
    var sample = [];
    for(var i=0;i<n;i++) {
      sample.push(this.splice(Math.random()*this.length,1));
    }
    return sample;
};
var sample = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10].sample_range(2);
```

Comment: Performance on this O(n*range). I wouldn't suggest using it. You'd be better off running n iterations of Knuth shuffle which would be O(n) if you assume the range array has already been created, O(n+range) otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to generate random numbers between 0 and `n`, one way is to randomly pick number `r1` in `0..n` then pick `r2` from `0..n-1` and add 1 to `r2` if `r2 >= r1`.

Answer (score 1):

```
function sample(range,tot){
    if(tot > range){
        alert('infinite loop?');
        return [];
    }
    var myRandomNumbers = [];
    for(var i = 0; i<tot; i++){
        var randN = Math.floor(Math.random()*range);
        while(myRandomNumbers.contains(randN)){
            randN = Math.floor(Math.random()*range);
        }
        myRandomNumbers.push(randN);
    }
    return myRandomNumbers
}

var nums = sample(10,2); //array containing 2 distinct random numbers
```

Answer (score 0):

Generate one, then repeatedly generate the second until it's not the same as the first.  Tiny chance it will have to run longer, but you won't see any performance hit unless you need to generate billions of numbers.